# How does the double が function in this sentence?

Tags: particle-が

I came across this sentence today 「アンタの本音が何で、嬢ちゃんが何を伝えたいかは俺にはハッキリ分かったがなぁ……」and was thrown off by the double が. I think I understand it but it still kinda puzzled me for a bit. Can some clarify this?

Comment: Can you describe in what sense you think there is a double が? What do you think the sentence means?

Comment: Actually going through it again kind of made me more confused now. I am guessing that is something like "why do I understand that you feel like there is something she is wants to tell you". I don't really know how to describe well how I think it is being used. I think it is just weird for me to parse.

Answer (score 3):

> 「アンタの本音が何で、嬢ちゃんが何を伝えたいかは俺にはハッキリ分かったがなぁ……」

So I think what is confusing you here is that you think 何で is "why". In this sentence it isn't.  アンタの本音が何で is a separate clause where で is the continuative form of だ. So in no sense is there any kind of double が thing happening.

The structure is "X and Y are clearly known to me" where X is アンタの本音が何で and Y is 嬢ちゃんが何を伝えたい.

Putting it together you get:

> What your true motive is, and what she wanted to convey, are clear to me.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. It is because even though there was a comma I was trying to parse the 何で with the other clause. This helps a lot!